# How do i make a discord bot login and read messages of a specific server to use in a windows form app?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I've made a windows forms app where I want to display the latest update of the program, using a discord bot to read the latest message in a text channel.

I'm having trouble running the function as well, since I haven't used `async` or `Task` in a function before.

Here's my code;

```
public async Task AnnounceAsync()
{
     string discordToken = Convert.ToString(123123123123123);
     await _discord.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, discordToken);
     await _discord.StartAsync();
     var chnl = _discord.GetChannel(123123123123123) as IMessageChannel;

     var message = chnl.GetMessageAsync(0, CacheMode.AllowDownload, RequestOptions.Default);
     Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd very much appreciate it!

Comment: I'd imagine that `GetMessageAsync` would return a `Task<T>`. You may want to do `var message = await chnl.GetMessageAsync(...)` instead, although this is based only on the name of the method.

Comment: I'm getting a exception when running it, using await or not. Exception thrown: 'Discord.Net.HttpException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @JohnnyMartinsson are you sure, that you awaited the method?

Comment: I had the exact same issue after they've changed the API. Why don't you try updating your nuget packages to make sure you are using the latest version of discord library?

Comment: I'm using the 2.0.1 version of discord.net.   This is the full code from calling it to the end(I did remove everything except the code to get the message)
https://pastebin.com/4wn7qdWK

Gettings these errors;
1
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Grafik.exe
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to call any actions directly related to the client right after the login action **will** throw a `NullReferenceException` since the client is yet to be ready at this state. Consider hooking the [Ready](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_DiscordSocketClient_Ready) event.

This phenomenon is described in the [Managing Connections with Discord.Net](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/concepts/connections.html) article on the official documentation.

Additionally, as others have pointed out, per TAP, you must `await` your `Task<T>` in order to properly get the result of such task.

Sample:

```
public async Task InitAsync()
{
    _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
    _client.Ready += OnReady;
    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, _token);
    await _client.StartAsync();
    // method will exit right away after start
    // halt the current task with Task.Delay
    await Task.Delay(-1);
}
private async Task OnReady()
{
    var channel = _client.GetChannel(_channelId) as ISocketMessageChannel;
    // bail if the channel type is not a message one
    if (channel == null) return;

    // no need to pass CacheMode and RequestOptions as they are optional
    // 1) CacheMode is default to always download especially if you do not 
    // have it enabled in the first place (see DiscordSocketConfig).
    // 2) RequestOptions should almost never be passed unless your request
    // requires specific "requests."
    // also, we await the task to actually get the result of this inquiry
    var msg = await channel.GetMessageAsync(_channelId);
    if (msg != null) Console.WriteLine(msg.Content);
}
```

### Side-note

With WinForm and any other .NET application that makes use of UI thread, you need to be especially careful when making calls. Consider looking into `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

#### Additional resources

- [Discord.Net documentation](https://docs.stillu.cc)
- [Don't block on Async Code - Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class:

```
public class DiscordServiceOptions
{
    public string BotToken { get; set; }
}

public class DiscordService : IDiscordService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _ready = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    public DiscordService(IOptions<DiscordServiceOptions> options, ILogger<DiscordService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _client.Log += LogDiscord;
        _client.Ready += OnReady;
        _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, options.Value.BotToken);
        _client.StartAsync();
    }

    public SocketTextChannel GetSocketTextChannel(ulong channelId) => _client.GetChannel(channelId) as SocketTextChannel;

    public async Task<bool> Ready()
    {
        await _ready.Task;
        return _ready.Task.Result;
    }

    private Task OnReady()
    {
        _ready.SetResult(true);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task LogDiscord(LogMessage msg)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(msg.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Create an interface:

```
interface IDiscordService
{
    public Task<bool> Ready();
    public SocketTextChannel GetSocketTextChannel(ulong channelId);
}
```

Add it in your program:

```
class Program
{
    private static ServiceProvider _services;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        _services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddOptions()
            .Configure<DiscordServiceOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.BotToken = "Your bot token";
            })
            .AddSingleton<IDiscordService, DiscordService>()
            .AddLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                logging.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions
                {
                    CaptureMessageTemplates = true,
                    CaptureMessageProperties = true
                });
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        Task discordReady = _services.GetService<IDiscordService>()
            .Ready();

        await discordReady;

        // maybe call other methods here?
        // write a discord message?
        var channel = _services.GetService<IDiscordService>()
            .GetSocketTextChannel(discordChannelId);

        await channel.SendMessageAsync("Hello World!")

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }
}
```